# Why is Ctrl + J not doing anything?

Tags: modeling, shortcut

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: [Create a Realistic City - Blender Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4ySFm4ey9U&t=328s)

At timestamp *6:38*, he selected all of the objects (using <kbd>A</kbd>) then joined them together using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. However, when I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, nothing seems to happen.

I am using Blender v2.78

Comment: make sure you have no, non mesh objects selected, you can't merge lamps or cameras, I'd suggest deleting anything that's not a mesh.

Comment: Also, you need an active object for join to work.  The active object is the last object you selected and has a brighter outline than the other selected objects.  If you just deleted an object its possible there was no active object when you did Ctrl+J.

Comment: You need an active object to enable joining - indicated by the object being slightly lighter than the other objects. Shift select one of the object and try again.

Comment: @ Firewill - it doesn't matter if you have other objects selected - even cameras and lamps - as Blender will just ignore them. As long as some of the objects are meshes and one mesh is active, joining will work for the mesh objects.

Comment: i noticed there is a bug in blender that sometimes CTRL+J will not join the objects. i have verified this.

Answer (score 3):

When your mouse cursor is hovering the 3D Viewport, it'll work.
But in other layers or areas, <kbd>CTRL+J</kbd> won't work.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a solution in GUI:

Step one: make sure the ojects that you want to join are of the same type, i.e. all are meshes.

Step two: select the first object.

Step three: select the second object.

Step four: click 'Join' button shown in the screenshot here (yellow arrow)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may have a different keybinding set for this shortcut. To make sure you're using the right one, navigate to the following:

File > User Preferences

[image]

Input > Enter *join* in the search bar > Under *Object Mode*, read the keybind.

As you can see here, my keybind for join is set to `J`

If you want to change it back to default, click *Restore*. Make sure to hit *Save User Settings* before exiting.

[image]

If you're changing the keybind to a completely different setting, make sure no other functions have that same keybind.

Answer (score 1):

### This solution worked for me:

- Select the 1st mesh in a collection.
- Then <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> select the last mesh in the collection.
- Then finally do <kbd>CTRL+J</kbd> while still selecting them.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -3):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> just at the beginning. When you import the city, press <kbd>A</kbd> then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>. It worked for me, hope it works for you, too.